# Repeating "<tag>key</tag> value" RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to figure out a RegEx pattern for parsing the following repeating sets, into two groups.

```
<tag>key:</tag> value; <tag>key</tag> value
```

The following pattern works for getting the keys only:

```
/<tag>(.*?)<\/tag>/g
```

However, if I add a repeating character group like this:

```
/<tag>(.*?)<\/tag>(.*)/g
```

Then I get the first key and everything else.  How can I get all character of the value before the next repetition of the key?

Comment: have you tried `<tag>([^<>]*?)<\/tag>([^<;]*)`, you can [test here](https://regex101.com/r/RK6GlV/1). it will capture lots of things though..

Comment: please stop attempting to parse HTML with regex. It is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Actually, you are looking for the [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/). It will pay-off down the road shortly.

Comment: @wp78de - Thanks! I'm using Html Agility Pack to get the key-value pattern I described, but I didn't think to go deeper with it. *facepalm*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try Regex: `<([^>]+)>([^<]*?)<\/\1>\s(\w*);?`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bnMH8a/1)

Comment: I've accepted this as an answer, because it does address what I asked.  However, my values may have spaces, which this will truncate.  I've decided to use Html Agility Pack instead.